# problems with building project after update to sdk28

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After updating Android Studio to SDK 28, my app doesn't build anymore. I always get this error, which I don't know what I can do with it:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\SDK\projects\EngineersWizard\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_form_beleuchtung.xml:18: error: attribute layout_scrollFlags (aka com.example.ren.engineerswizard:layout_scrollFlags) not found.
C:\SDK\projects\EngineersWizard\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_form_beleuchtung.xml:35: error: resource string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior (aka com.example.ren.engineerswizard:string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Maybe anybody has an idea?

Comment: can you provide your layout file?

Comment: Ok. I found out what was the problem. For some reason the TabLayout definitions were not installed anymore. By installing them (by clicking on the download-symbol near 'TabLayout' in the Palette of the Design-View of the Layout) the issue was solved and my app builds again.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK Build-Tools is a component of the Android SDK required for building Android apps. It's installed in the /build-tools/ directory.

You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies. To use a different version of the build tools, specify it using buildToolsVersion in your module's build.gradle, as follows:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
...
}
```